# IOS : Errors while compiling projet with MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, ios, libxml2, mgtwitterengine

i m getting this error on some machines while compiling my project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
"_xmlFree", referenced from:
-[MGTwitterLibXMLParser initWithXML:delegate:connectionIdentifier:requestType:responseType:URL:]     in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o
-[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValueAsString] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o
-[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValueAsDate] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o
-[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValueAsInt] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o
-[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValueAsBool] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o
```

It compiles fine in simulator mode but not of devices (ios 4.3)

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3):

Add libxml2 framework to your target.

In Xcode 3, you do that by right clicking on Frameworks in the sidebar and choosing "Add Existing Framework". I don't know how you do it in Xcode 4, sorry.

From the MGTwitterEngine readme:

> 1. Add libxml2.dylib in Other Frameworks. You'll find the library
>      in:
>
>    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib
> 2. Add "$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2" as a Header Search Path in your
>      Project Settings.

Comment: i ve already done that , otherwise i guess if would not compile in simulator , is there any specific action to do for devices?

Answer (score 1):

Replaced lib with `libxml2.dylib` by `libxml2.2.dylib`

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue some days ago, and i follow below steps:

- You just need to add libxml2.dylib framework.
- and add **/usr/include/libxml2** in Header Search path.

It worked for me.